# Gimme questions for beer pros/experts?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In order to generate more site traffic, are more basic questions okay?

It seems like the questions lately are either mythbuster, or esoteric questions that might not have a definitive answer.  Would generic questions about styles or history be beneficial to the site or is that not the goal?

Is it too general to have questions like:
What is a (style X) beer?  Tagged: history, Style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely okay! These types of questions are in fact encouraged. We have a few such questions out there already:

- [What is a "White IPA" and is it actually an IPA?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/768/what-is-a-white-ipa-and-is-it-actually-an-ipa)
- [What's the difference between a porter and a stout?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/33/whats-the-difference-between-a-porter-and-a-stout)
- [What should I expect from a Belgian triple (tripel)?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-should-i-expect-from-a-belgian-triple-tripel)
- [What are the difference between a dubbel and a tripel?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/602/what-are-the-difference-between-a-dubbel-and-a-tripel)

So far they appear to be tagged [style](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) and [classification](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification). I like your [history](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) suggestion as well.

I think Beer.SE is still in a flexible, forgiving phase where we're still trying to figure out what exactly is too subjective or too definitive, so don't be shy to ask any question, especially if it's a real question you or someone you know actually has about a beer. That said, thanks for asking—it helps for people to know, especially  since Beer.SE still lacks a clear "What can I ask here?" FAQ.